# Display last Fragment of Activity when coming back from other Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I have `MainActivity` & `SettingsActivity`

`MainActivity` holds 2 fragments: `FirstFragment` & `SyncFragment`

From `SyncFragment` I go to `SettingsActivity`. My expectation was that I find the Fragment displayed in MainActivity the same as when I left it. But this is not the case depending on how I go back.

*Scenario1*: If I click the top "Back" button (the back arrow in the topbar), the MainActivity goes back to FirstFragment.

*Scenario2*: If I click the bottom "Back" button (the triangular one at the bottom of the screen from the topbar), the MainActivity goes back to SyncFragment

**In Scenario1** the Activity seems reloaded from scratch, while in scenario2 it isn't.

I tried to store the fragment that was displayed onPause or onSaveInstanceStage, but I noticed that savedInstanceState is always null which doesn't seem normal to me. *Why is savedInstanceState always null? What am I missing there?*

The workaround I'm using right now is to change "`launchMode`" in the manifest to "`singleTop`" instead of "standard" which 'fixes' by having same behavior as with scenario2, but *is it correct to do it that way?*

**In scenario2** if I change some setting in the SettingsActivity, the value of the setting I used to display in SyncFragment is not updated accordingly. *Is is normal that I have to update the view in onResume?* I guess it is according to lifecycle of the Fragment/Activity. (note that I have an onSharedPreferenceChanged in the Fragment which isn't called when I change the setting in SettingsActivity)

---

In `MainActivity.java` I have:

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
    }
```

In `activity_main.xml` there is the toolbar (inside a com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout)

```xml
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.***.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Edit the question and post the code you are using to control the back arrow button on the toolbar at the top. It looks like this code is launching the `MainActivity` again, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I added the requested code.